# Filtering with logical + NA values in one column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("Logical"=c("true",NA,"false","true","","false"),
             "Numeric"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

unique(df$Logical)
length(df$Logical == TRUE)
```

I'm trying to figure out, how many `TRUE`-values do I have in my `df$Logical` column. But seems I'm missing something and `length(df$Logical == TRUE)` returns no of records in my logical column.

What I'm doing wrong in this particular case. Desired result should be 2 for `TRUE`-values in `df$Logical` column. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to specify the string in the lower case as the values were 'true/false' and not exactly `TRUE/FALSE`.  Also, instead of `length`, `sum` should be used.  The `sum` gets the number of TRUE elements.

```
sum(df$Logical == "true")
#[1] 2
```

If there are NA elements in the column, use `na.rm = TRUE`

```
sum(df$Logical=='true', na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2
```

The `length` of a logical or any other vector would be the same as the original length/number of rows of the dataset.

```
length(df$Logical == "true")
#[1] 6
```

because it returns a logical vector of `length` 6.

```
df$Logical == "true"
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

To get the counts of both `true` and `false`, we can use `table`

```
table(df$Logical)
```

Comment: I made a correction in my input data frame (df). In case I've added there NA value, it computes also with NA.

Comment: @martinkabe The `NA` should be without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all "true" and "false" as you put it into you data frame are not Booleans but simple strings.

Moreover, `length(df$Logical == TRUE)` will always return 6 in this example, i.e. the number of elements in the column. This is because `df$Logical == TRUE` returns a sequence of TRUE or FALSE. In your case it will return

```
FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

because the boolean expression is never true. However, the length of this will be 6 as returned by `length()`.

To overcome the problem you might define your data frame like this

```
df <- data.frame("Logical"=c(TRUE,NA,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE),
         "Numeric"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

And then you can sum up the number of `TRUE`

```
sum(df$Logical == TRUE, na.rm = T)
[1] 2
```

`na.rm = T` is important here because otherwise the sum will return `NA` if one more more elements are `NA`.

Alternatively, you can work with strings to indicate true or false (and empty strings a NA)

Then you could write

```
df <- data.frame("Logical"=c("true",NA,"false","true","","false"),
             "Numeric"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

sum(df$Logical == "true", na.rm = T)
[1] 2
```